# How to import XML data in using .NET and C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd

I have a set of xsd files and xml data files. I need to import data from xml files to database. I have .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010.

Which tools can I use? Ideally it should be something, what helps me to read data as entities composed from xml structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101112/best-practice-using-c-sharp-xsd-typed-datasets-in-enterprise-applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd look into using `xsd.exe` to generate c# classes that adhere to the format specified in the xsd. From there you can use the XmlSerialization objects in .Net to hydrate some objects of the classes generated from `xsd.exe`. You can then parse your objects however you'd like to in your c# code from there.

Here's a link that may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yojoshi/archive/2011/05/14/xml-serialization-and-deserialization-entity-classes-with-xsd-exe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With latest VS version, don't need to use xsd.exe anymore.

Look at topic :
[XML 2 CS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)
use Method 2 in comments